# Android llamada de telefono desde webview en un viewpager

Tags: android, html, webview, android-viewpager

Tengo un viewpager de paginas web. Es muy sencillo y funciona bien. Pero al pulsar el enlace de llamada `href="tel:971142254">`, intenta acceder a pagina web y me da error. He probado con esto, pero me da el mismo error.

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,
                    Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
        }else if(url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:")) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Os dejo el codigo.
Gracias y un saludo.

```
public class Comercio2 extends FragmentActivity{

    ViewPager pager;
    FragmentStatePagerAdapter adapter;

    /* Just some random URLs
    *
    * Each page of our pager will display one URL from this array
    * Swiping, to the right will take you to the next page having
    * the next URL.
    */
    String[] toVisit={
            "http://www.angoher2.com/alimenta1b.html",
            "http://www.angoher2.com/alimenta2b.html",
            "http://www.angoher2.com/alimenta3b.html",            
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.comercio2);
        pager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.container2);

        TabLayout container_tab2 = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.container_tab2);
        container_tab2.setupWithViewPager(pager, true);

        adapter=new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()){

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                // This makes sure getItem doesn't use a position
                // that is out of bounds of our array of URLs
                return toVisit.length;
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {

                    // Here is where all the magic of the adapter happens
                // As you can see, this is really simple.
                return Fragment_Web.newInstance(toVisit[position]);
            }
        };

        //Let the pager know which adapter it is supposed to use
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**Este es el fragment.**

```
public class Fragment_Web extends Fragment{

    WebView browser;
    String url;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_web, container, false);
        browser=(WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.my_browser);
        browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        browser.loadUrl(url);

        return view;
    }

    // This is the method the pager adapter will use
    // to create a new fragment
    public static Fragment newInstance(String url){

        Fragment_Web f = new Fragment_Web();
        f.url = url;
        return f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En tu primer fragmento de código que dices que no te ayudó a solucionar tu problema, cámbialo por esto:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url.startsWith("tel:")) { 
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url)); 
        startActivity(intent);
        view.reload();
        return true;
    }

    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}
```

Otras posibles soluciones:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338305/android-webview-tel-links-show-web-page-not-found

Comment: Lo he probado con el codigo que has colgado y tambien he probado con los ejemplo del link. He hecho todas las combinaciones que se me han ocurrido, pero no he conseguido activar el DIAL. Al final lo que he hecho es poner los telefonos en un array con indice en el numero de fragmen y a traves de codigo activar DIAL. El resultado es el que yo queria.